# Conditions to become a basis for Complex Numbers vector space.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let C(R) be the vector space of complex numbers over the field of real numbers. Under what conditions on the real numbers a, b, c, d in the set S = { a+ib, c+id } do we have L(S) = C where L(S) denotes linear span of S. Justify your claim.

How to solve above question.

My approach: 
The Basis for C is { 1, i }. So the conditions are a = 0, d = 0 OR b = 0, c =0. Is my approach right? Please give your opinions.

Comment: Not quite - there exist bases of $\mathbb{C}$ that don't satisfy these conditions (for example, $\{1+i, 1-i\}$). Think about what conditions are required for a basis.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $(a+bi)$ and $(c+di)$ should not satisfy $$\alpha(a+bi) + \beta(c+di)=0$$ for any real $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and $\alpha,\beta\neq0$ simultaneously.